# ¿Como muestro en flutter los datos de mi perfil logueado en google, en una nueva "page"?

Tags: login, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Yo cree un login con google en una aplicación de flutter, de momento eso funciona, pero ahora necesito que al darle en el boton "login" me mande a una nueva pagina y en esa enseñar la foto que me proporciona mi cuenta de google. Pero cada vez que lo hago me da el siguiente error:

> The getter 'photoUrl' was called on null.

Este sería el codigo la clase le llame logueadoPage

```
class LogueadoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogueadoPageState createState() => _LogueadoPageState();
}

class _LogueadoPageState extends State<LogueadoPage> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  FirebaseUser _user;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Google Logueado"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_user.photoUrl),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

y desde la pagina de login mando todo así:
//el diseñode login

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}
 FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser _user;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("google Authentication"),
          ),
          body:Center(
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      handleSignIn().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('pagina'));

                    },
                    child: Text("SignIn with Goolge"),
                  ),
                ));
  }
```

//metodo de login

```
Future<void> handleSignIn() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    AuthResult result = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
    print(result);
    _user = result.user;

    setState(() {
      isSignIn = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: En `LogueadoPage _user.photoUrl` es null por que `FirebaseUser _user;` es solo una variable la cual no a sido inicializada. Ahora en `handleSignIn()` lo ideal seria que expusieras `_user = result.user;` a todo el proyecto con algún manejador de estados (Provider, Bloc). Seria posible que compartieras el repositorio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente tienes que pasarle el usuario a la segunda ruta. En tu código necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

Que tu función regrese el usuario.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async {
    ...
    AuthResult result = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
    print(result);
    return result.user;
}
```

En el botón manda llamar la función para que te regrese el usuario y pasarlo a tu nueva ruta.

```
onPressed: () async {
  var user = await handleSignIn();
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('pagina', arguments: user);
},
```

El la clase state de la segunda ruta `state` puedes acceder al usuario del widget

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseUser user = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    ...
  }
```

Esta es lo más basico para hacer funcionar lo que quieres. Para algo más robusto necesitas algo como un inherited widget.